# Bash script doesn't work as cronjob

Tags: bash, cron

Hi i wrote the following bash script:

```
cat /home/xyz/wlandiscovery.sh
#!/bin/bash


DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y__%H:%M:%S`

#Get the current standard interface e.g. eth0
INTERFACE=`route | grep '*' | awk '{print $8}'`

#Check if mac is available
if /usr/bin/arp-scan --interface $INTERFACE -l -r 5 | grep "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
then
     echo -e "$DATE AVAILABLE!" >> /home/xyz/wlandiscovery.log
else
    echo -e "$DATE NOT AVAILABLE" >> /home/xyz/wlandiscovery.log
fi

exit 0
```

If i run this and the mac is available i get "AVAILABLE", if i disconnect the device it give "NOT AVAILABLE"...so run as expected.

But if i run it as Cronjob every 5 Minutes I get always "NOT AVAILABLE": (on a Debian system)

```
crontab -e

#......
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/xyz/wlandiscovery.sh
```

Whats the problem here?

Comment: No need to pipe `grep` to `awk`: `awk '/\*/{print $8}'` will do just as well.

Comment: What are the permissions of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INTERFACE=`route | grep '*' | awk '{print $8}'`
```

On my system, route is `/usr/sbin/route`. `/usr/sbin` is most likely not in cron's PATH. Specify the full path:

```
INTERFACE=`/usr/sbin/route | awk '$2 == "*" {print $8}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the command line output of the following on your Mac and Debian boxes:
INTERFACE=`route | grep '*' | awk '{print $8}'`

Is it the same? It should be in order to work.

Then, compare the command line output of:
/usr/bin/arp-scan --interface $INTERFACE -l -r 5 | grep "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now its working. seems that $PATH with crontab is not equal to $PATH in my Terminal prompt... if i do /sbin/route and /usr/bin/awk and /bin/grep it works.